# Installing XCode 4.2.1 on OS X 10.7.2 using App Store

Tags: xcode4, xcode4.2

I am trying to install Xcode 4.2.1 from App Store on my iMac running OS X 10.7.2 and when I started the installation by clicking on the Install button in the App Store on my iMac, it changed to Installing but it doesn't show any progress bar indicating the status or percentage of progress of the installation. Is this how it is supposed to be? How long does it take to install? I had uninstalled my previous Xcode 4.1 earlier before starting the Xcode 4.2.1 installation.

Comment: This also happened to me for 4.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me. I rebooted and it worked properly.

Answer (score 4):

Look for `Install Xcode.app` in your `Applications` directory. Try to run it manually (that's what I had to do). I've also seen the recommendation to `chmod +x` on the installation app as well -- I didn't need to do that.